# Ajax Html Forms with PHP, Jquery and MYSQL,

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I understand this question may be entirely juvenile however I have been trying to debug it for an entire afternoon, not using an IDE other than sublime. would be really glad to receive any help and format this question nicely for future begineers when it works.

currently

my html.

```
<?php
  //connect to the server & database
  $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','ikea');

  if(!$connect)
  {
    echo "failed to connect ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  // query the database
  $query = 'SELECT * from department 
            where iconpath Like "image%"
            order by name asc';
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

  // retrieve the resultset
  while( $row[] = $result->fetch_object());
?>
    <form id="question2" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <select style="width:8.7cm;" id="member_choice" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
            <?php foreach($row as $option) : ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $option->name; ?>"><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select><br/><br/>
           <button id="q2-submit" name="q2-submit" style="margin-left:5cm;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-add"> Get Departments! </button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

my jquery

```
$('#question2').on('submit', function() 
{
   alert("submit!");

    // AJAX STUFF HERE
    $.post('q3.php', function(data)
    {
        console.log("here1");
        $(".return").html(data);
    });
});
```

and currently experimenting with my php trying to get it to return "content"

```
<?php
   echo "content";
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? get the PHP script to return "content" upon `#q2-submit` click event?

Comment: OT: the `label` is useless. It needs the `for` attribute to point at the `id` of the form element it is supposed to be associated with.

Comment: so what's the problem? is js not working? "content" is not returned? what?

Comment: yes the js is not working. @echolocation yes I am.

Comment: you shouldn't use click event, you should use submit event for form

Comment: @decker modified to submit. still no alert.

Comment: @laycat added codepen to answer, try it out

Comment: @laycat if you still are not getting the expected results it might be a problem with the data returned from q2.php, and maybe would be a new question?

Comment: @thank you decker! yes Decker I found it curious and you were right. it was a problem with the data returned.

Comment: @laycat - You should make a new question instead of completely changing this one every time ;) Now the original answers make no sense

Comment: @decker its ok I hope to refine it and edit your answer so it will be a good guide for anyone in future. the title is pretty legit :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question keeps changing. Honestly, I recommend you go through a tutorial on how to submit a form using AJAX with jQuery, like [this one](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery).

---

You should use submit handler instead of a click handler. Also your selector is wrong.

## HTML

added `name` attribute to the `<select>` tag.

```
<form id="question2" method="POST" action="q2.php">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <label>Select Member Card Number</label>
    <select name="member_choice" style="width:8.7cm;" id="member_choice" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
      <?php foreach($row as $option) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option->name; ?>"><?php echo $option->name; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br/><br/>
     <button style="margin-left:5cm;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-add"> Get Departments! </button>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$('#question2').on('submit', function(event) 
{
    // stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var url = $form.attr('action');

    $.post(url, $form.serialize(), function(data)
    {
        console.log("here1");
        $('#content').html(data.content);
    });

});
```

## PHP (q2.php)

```
<?php

    $content = $_POST['member_choice'];

    echo json_encode($content);

?>
```

Comment: trying this out now (:

Comment: it still doesn't return "content" in content div do you mind taking a look have updated the new edits

Comment: @laycat I forgot () on .serialize()

Answer (score -1):

Your click handler doesn't prevent the form from submitting (the page gets refreshed) so you never see the ajax response. Use a submit handler instead:

```
$('#question2').on('submit',function(e) 
{
    var name = $('#department_choice :selected').val();
        console.log("here");
        $(".return").html("asdad");

    $.post('q2.php', function(data)
    {
        console.log("here1");
        $(".return").html(data);
    });

    return false;//prevent form submit

});
```